# How can I return a value from a c program to the back script that calls it?

Tags: c, bash, return, call

I'm trying to solve a problem where I want a bash script to call a `c` program and a value from the `c` program to be returned to the bach script and be stored in a variable.

Here is an example (code isn't really written properly):

Bash script:

```
$value = ./foo
echo $value
```

C program:

```
int main() {
    //Have a value here that is returned to the variable 'value' in the bash script.
    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: print the value to stdout and then capture it

Comment: So something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command)? If so, you'll want to use printf statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the return value of the last program you executed by using `$?` or you can print the value to stdout and then capture it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("my_value");
    return 0;
}
```

and then in bash do

```
value=$(./my_program)
echo $value
```

the result will be `my_value`

Answer (score 1):

Print the value to stdout in your c program:

```
printf("%s",value);
```

or

```
printf("%s\n",value);
```

Your bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

value="$(your_c_program)"
echo "$value"
```

Answer (score 0):

To have you script echo the value returned from your C application, do

```
echo $?
```

<sub>Not a C question though</sub>